# hidden shortcut

Tags: shortcuts

When I combine ctrl + shift + alt + C system open terminal. I can't find any reference to this shortcut, I tried to find something in keyboard in Ubuntu and using dconf-editor and nothing help.
Are there any places where I can seach shorctuts

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. What did you try, and what did not work according to your expectation. Or are you merely asking where to search shortcuts? If that is the case, then rephrase your question and title to focus on only that question.

Comment: I want to delete shorcut, but I don't know where to find. I google only two place where shortcuts store, but neither of this places show this shortcut

Comment: ctrl + shift + alt + C is not normally defined as a shortcut in Ubuntu. Did you look under "Custom shortcuts"? Else, you could connect a different keyboard to see whether this is a problem with your current keyboard only or not.